# zclip not working for the non DOM ready html entities?

Tags: jquery, zclip

I am using zclip plugin to copy the clipboard, here the copy function only working on the second click

Following is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clip_copy').click(function () {
        $('#clip_copy').zclip({
            path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: function () {
                return $('input#shrink_url_copy').val();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

here the `shrink_url_copy` set into `display:none` on the DOM load, so I think that is the problem here, what I have to do work with the first click?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are binding zclip after the first click.

Edit: What you'll want to do is find the code that is removing `display:none`. You can attach the zclip function within the handler, like this:

```
$('input#shrink_url_copy').show(function(){
  $('#clip_copy').zclip({
    path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function () {
      return $('input#shrink_url_copy').val();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: However, if i use without click, nothing seems work even on the double click?? but without the display:none it is working both for click and zclip

Comment: @kan You'll want to bind zclip within the handler that shows the hidden element.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this out:-

`zclip` is getting called once you click on it which is causing it to work after your first click.

Call the `zclip` on dom ready event not on the click event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
        $('#clip_copy').zclip({
            path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: function () {
                return $('input#shrink_url_copy').val();
            }
        });        
});
```

Comment: However, if i use without click, nothing seems work even on the double click?? but without the display:none it is working both for click and zclip